# Center align a div that has no width defined

Tags: html, css

Very simple question: What is the CORRECT way of center aligning a div that has no set width?
Doing this for a div:

```
.class div{
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 300px;
}
```

will align the div horizontally center, but NOT if you remove the set width.

However, this does the trick, but is it the correct way?

```
.class div{
    margin: 0 auto; 
    display: table;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Also, text-align: center also seems to center the contents of the div...I have an image inside the div

Comment: Nothing wrong with the second bit of code that i can see. Does the job doesn't it? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="class"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
 text-align:center;
}
.class{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}
```